# Do I need a transit visa at Minsk airport (from Warsaw to Moscow)?

Tags: visas, airports, transit-visas, chinese-citizens, belarus

On Nov. 16, I will fly from Warsaw to Moscow via Minsk.

I stay in the airport only for 1.5 hours.

I am a Chinese citizen. I have a Russian tourist visa. I have already booked the ticket.

The airline is Belavia.

Comment: Yes, you need a transit visa. Flights between Belarus and Russia are deemed domestic, therefore you'll have to go through passport control at Minsk.

Comment: But I called Balavia and she told me I do not need

Comment: Sorry, your question is just not logical. Aeroflot does not fly Kiev-Minsk. And why do you need to fly to Minsk if you need to go to India, or even to Moscow?

Comment: @ach WRONG. There's a dedicated passport control for Belarus -> Russia transfers, for which no Belarusian transit visa is needed

Comment: @Crazydre, WRONG. My reply was given in 2015, and the situation might have changed since, don't you think? Moreover, I last flew EU-MSQ-RU last year and there was no such dedicated passport control then.

Comment: @ach I've transited MSQ multiple times in 2018, 2019 and 2020 (not going to/from Russia though). The dedicated passport control is at one far end of the departures area. In other words, you'd follow the transfer signs, clear ticket+security control, enter the departures area and then clear the "Transfer to Russia" passport control.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Belarusian Airlines [website](http://en.belavia.by/faq):

> **Is the transit visa needed?**
>
> According to the information, obtained from National airport Minsk border guard service:
>
> Those passengers, who travel in transit through Minsk, **do not need the Belarusian transit visa**, if the following conditions are fulfilled:
>
> - passengers have a valid passport and valid documents (national passport and/or visa , etc.) required for entry into the country of destination;
> - valid single ticket for the entire route to the destination point;
> - **stay in Minsk does not exceed 24 hours and the passenger does not leave the so-called airport transit zone**.

[Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external-result/e3KzS95u3btpEDF_PXmrFn8S9ebOQAt1qYSeUEWHG5o) confirms this as well:

[image: belarus transit visa]

So the answer is: **no**, you do not need a transit visa.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy forum reviews confirm that it is also possible when flying to Moscow: http://forum.awd.ru/viewtopic.php?f=852&t=134949&start=20

Comment: OK, I don't understand how it's working, but never mind, I revoke my comment.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy It probably works similar to UK-Ireland transit.

Comment: I actually did do that, transiting through UK to Ireland. I had a UK visa (which was stamped on that occasion), and I suppose I could very well remain in the UK, had I changed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit confused, but it seems **you might not need one** if you stay in the airport, judging by this [thread](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g294447-i5625-k5723942-o50-Transit_Visa_Minsk_Airport-Belarus.html) (Oct 2015)

However Belarus does have a transit visa which allows up to 2 days of travel across the country, but I'm assuming that's literally just to go across on your way somewhere else and [WikiVoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Belarus) seems to go in that direction as well because only the train travel section mentions transit visas while the air travel doesn't. In any case, Chinese citizens are **not** exempt of visas for [Belarus](http://www.belarus.by/en/travel/travel-visas).

If you decide to apply for one anyway just to be safe, you can get one at the airport but you need to send in some documentation ahead of time, at least 3 days before